# Join parts of URL in Julia

Tags: url, julia

I am looking for the "best" way in the `Julia Programming Language` to join parts of a URL into a single URL similar to `joinurl` in `Python`.

The full functionality of `Python`'s `joinurl` is not needed. I'd like to achieve that extra frontslashes are added but also excess frontslashes are remove if needed, i.e.
`julia_joinurl("http://localhost/","/index.html") == "http://localhost/index.html"`
and
`julia_joinurl("http://localhost","index.html") == "http://localhost/index.html"`.

Is there a Julia package that implements such a high-level function? Or how would I implement this otherwise?

Comment: As mentioned by Cameron, the Python function is called `urllib.parse.urljoin` instead of `joinurl`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a `joinurl` function in Python, so I'm guessing you're referring to `urllib.parse.urljoin` in the Python standard library. There is a function similar to that in the [HTTP.jl](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl) package. It creates a URI from the components of the URI:

```js
julia> HTTP.URI(scheme="http", host="example.com", path="/index.html")
HTTP.URI("http://example.com/index.html")
```

However, it's not as forgiving as the Python `urljoin` function. You have to start the `path` argument with a `/` and you cannot end the `host` argument with a `/`:

```js
julia> HTTP.URI(scheme="http", host="example.com", path="index.html")
ERROR: ArgumentError: merge(::HTTP.URIs.URI; scheme::String, userinfo::SubString{String},
host::String, port::SubString{String}, path::String, query::SubString{String},
fragment::SubString{String}) requires !(scheme in ["http", "https"]) ||
(isempty(path) || path[1] == '/')

julia> HTTP.URI(scheme="http", host="example.com/", path="/index.html")
ERROR: ArgumentError: merge(::HTTP.URIs.URI; scheme::String, userinfo::SubString{String},
host::String, port::SubString{String}, path::String, query::SubString{String},
fragment::SubString{String}) requires isempty(host) || host[end] != '/'
```

Comment: You are totally right, I meant the `urllib.parse.urljoin` function. I was tricked by the renaming in this [post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/join-parts-of-a-url-joinpath/12441/13?u=uwechsler) xD Thank you! Do you know if it it is deliberately made  more "restrictive" than `urljoin `?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be deliberate, since the error messages say that `path` must satisfy `path[1] == '/'` and `host` must satisfy `host[end] != '/'`.